# Problems with the applying material using geometry nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

I need to assign a specific material to the mesh using geometry nodes to make it look like a face.

[image]

And so that I can switch between different "faces" with a boolean (or other) switch.

The way I did it doesn't work.

[image]

Using vertex groups I was not able to create the correct eyes and other details.

[image]
(Blender v 3.3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node `Set Material` changes the material in the domain *Faces*.

Your vertex group, however, is, as the name suggests, in the domain *Point*.

Therefore, all faces that have any of their points in the vertex group will be selected.

For this reason you have to use the node `Interpolate Domain` (Blender 3.3), which explicitly selects only the faces whose points are all in the vertex group.

However, this alone is not sufficient in this concrete case, because there are at least four faces here, where all points are also in the vertex group, but which are not to be selected.

Therefore, you would have to subdivide the mesh further beforehand in order to make the selection more precise:

[image]

Comment: So i need to subdivide all the hexagons so that they have a vertex in the middle? Is there a way to do this quickly?

Comment: @arachnoden Yes, unfortunately, because otherwise this selection can not be achieved or processed as you want in *Geometry Nodes*. You can quickly achieve this with the modifier *Subdivision*.